# Is $e^{i\theta}$ where $\theta = \frac{2\pi}{n}, n \in \mathbb{N}$ algebraic over $\mathbb{Q}$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, extension-field

I am not sure how to come up with a $p(x) \in \mathbb{Q}[x]$ such that $e^{i\theta}$ is a solution so I feel like it is not algebraic over $\mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: What is $(e^{i \theta})^n$?

Comment: $~e^{i\theta}~$ is one of the roots of the *algebraic* equation $~z^n - 1 = 0.$

Answer (score 0):

The complex number $e^{2\pi i/n}$ is one of the roots of $x^n-1$.
It is called an $n$th [root of unity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root_of_unity).